# How React Testing Library can assert children props and Redux store updates?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I just started exploring a unit testing framework for my react application. I locked my choice at `@testing-library/react` instead of `Enzyme` as it is recommended by React and helps writing more robust tests. I'm also planning to use `Jest` for completeness.

But before I could proceed with `React Testing Library`, I'm stuck at few questions. Can someone please help?

For instance,

1. There is an `Editor` component which updates Redux store based on user input.
2. There is another component `Preview` which reads value directly from store.
3. There is a third component `Container` which contains both of the above components passing some props.

Questions:

1. How to test if user input in `Editor` component actually updates store?
2. How to test if `Preview` component can render value reading from store?
3. How to test if `Container` component passes props correctly to its children?

**Container.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Editor from './Editor';
import Preview from './Preview';

const Container = ({editorType}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor type={editorType} />
      <Preview />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Container;
```

**Editor.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {setName} from './actions';

const Editor = ({type}) => {
  const name = useSelector(state => state.name);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Type: {type}</h1>
      <input value={name} onChange={evt => dispatch(setName(evt.target.value))} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Editor;
```

**Preview.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Editor = ({type}) => {
  const name = useSelector(state => state.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Name: {name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Preview;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it :

**How to test if user input in Editor component actually updates store?**

Looking at your code, Editor does not update store, it does not call useDispatch. But assuming it does, using https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store I would setup a mocked store provider to the component in the test, then trigger user input and check the mocked store if the correct action have been dispatched, with the correct payload :

```
describe('<Editor />', () => {
  let store: MockStoreEnhanced;
  let rtl: RenderResult;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({ /* your store structure */ });

    rtl = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Editor type={...} />
      </Provider>
    );
  });

  test('dispatch action correctly', () => {
    fireEvent.change(rtl.container.querySelector('input'), { target: {value: 'test' } });

    // check actions that were dispatched by change event
    // getActions return an array avec redux actions (type, payload)
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(...);
  }
}
```

Beside of this you should test your store reducer and action creators, to ensure that the action modifies the store correctly.

**How to test if Preview component can render value reading from store?**

Same principle, setup your test with a mocked store, init this store with relevant value, and just test that the component displays what's in the store :

```
describe('<Preview />', () => {
  let store: MockStoreEnhanced;
  let rtl: RenderResult;

   beforeEach(() => {
     store = mockStore({ name: 'This is name from store' });

     rtl = render(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <Preview type={...} />
       </Provider>
     );
   });

   test('displays store content correctly', () => {
     expect(rtl.getByText('This is name from store')).toBeTruthy();
   }
 }
```

**How to test if Container component passes props correctly to its children?**

Here you should test Container + Preview + Editor together, and find something visual to test (as a real user would perceive it), involving the props passed by Container to its children.

For example, if Preview displays props.type, which comes from Container editorType props :

```
describe('<Container />', () => {
  // mocked store may not be necessary here, depending on your use case
  let store: MockStoreEnhanced;
  let rtl: RenderResult;

   beforeEach(() => {
     store = mockStore({ name: 'This is name from store' });

     rtl = render(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <Container editorType={'toTest'} />
       </Provider>
     );
   });

   test('displays store content correctly', () => {
     // check that 'toTest' exists in DOM because it is rendered by Preview component, a child of Container
     expect(rtl.getByText('toTest')).toBeTruthy();
   }
 }
```

To sum it up, my approach would be :

- Test actions and reducers alone (very simple to test, state machines, just plain Jest tests)
- Test that components dispatch correct actions with correct payloads on correct user inputs
- Mock store to setup relevant use cases (init store value) for components reading data from store

For the last 2 items I use https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store.

Comment: not calling dispatch in my example was a miss. I just updated it. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: Your answers are perfect to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! This is some kind of personal strategy, which I combine with Cypress E2E tests.

Comment: Can't we use the actual store used in the app instead of mocked one in the tests? Also, how to test async actions?

Comment: Yes, you can also chose not to mock redux store, it's tour call. To test async actions, mock your async function (the one which make the http request) with a Promise.resolve or Promise.reject , then check that the correct actions have been dispatched (start, success, error)